# Stripe - Blazor - Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, stripe-payments, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I've create a Blazor WASM app that uses the Stripe’s browser-side library, Stripe.js for Credit Card processing.  It works perfectly on the localhost in VS Studio.  I've even created a Stripe webhook controller on the server app that works(with the help of the Stripe CLI to forward to the LocalHost).  The issue is when I deploy to an Azure WebApp when it goes to redirect to Stripe, I get the usual Blazor 'Nothing at this Address' router error page.

I'm thinking it might be a Cors issue?  I've tried adding this to the server app Startup:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithOrigins("https://checkout.stripe.com",
                                                          "https://m.stripe.com",
                                                          "https://js.stripe.com",
                                                          "https://api.stripe.com")
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                                      .AllowAnyMethod();
                                  });
            });
```

But since the redirect actually happens on the client app, not sure this is correct and not sure how to add to the client app. (I added all the Stripe addresses I could find in the browser, but not sure if that is even correct).

Also there a no errors or issue when looking through the browser debug tool.

Any help/direction would be much appreciated.
Mike

Comment: can you add screenshot with the url of browser?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the url was this incredibly long string mixed with a bunch of crazy characters but after scrolling through it, I did see a bit about No API Key.  When deployed, it's suppose to get that from the Key Vault, but I had a config mistake.  Once corrected, it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you put your solution and post your answer below ? Which can help more forum users. ^-^